# Comparing the background resources of buttons

Tags: android

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.Drawable.abc);
if ( button.getBackground()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc))
{
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xyz);
}

else if( button.getBackground()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xyz) )
{
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc);
}
```

I want to compare the background images set on the button. The above code has been taken from Stack Overflow... but it doesn't seem to work

Please suggest a better method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
if ( button.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc).getConstantState())
{
     button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xyz);
}
```

Comment: Though Android Studio didn't argue on this, but the approach didn't work out recently. Maybe "right" approach has changed a bit? I've tried both ways - the one in the question and the one in the answer.