# Android Java check for drawable / disable click

Tags: java, android, drawable, clickable

I want to check if a button has a drawable / color and if it has the drawable of

> border_inner_grey

I want to disable the click on that button.
I tried this but I did not work.

How do I accomplish this?

```
final Button button01 = (Button) android.findViewById(R.id.test);

if(button01.getBackground().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_inner_grey).getConstantState())) {
        button01.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        button01.setClickable(true);
    }
```

Comment: How do you set the background in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing the background resources of buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976601/comparing-the-background-resources-of-buttons)

Comment: how is the world is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
if (button01.getBackground().getConstantState() ==
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_inner_grey).getConstantState())
```